# Remover sinal de negativo de input number

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código em jquery:

```
$.each(data.Dados, function (i, val) {
   tr += '<tr>';
   tr += '<td><div class="product" style="margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><div class="product-info" style="margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><h3 class="product-title">' + data.Dados[i].post_title + '</h3></div></div></td>';
   tr += '<td style="text-align:center;" class="price-col" data-id-cart="' + data.Dados[i].post_id + '" id="preco_' + data.Dados[i].post_id + '">' + data.Dados[i].post_valor + '</td>';
   tr += '<td style="text-align:center;padding:0;" class="quantity-col"><input data-mask="00" data-mask-selectonfocus="true" style="margin:0;" onfocus="campoTexto(this, 1)" onblur="campoTexto(this, 0)" type="number" onChange="Multiplica(' + data.Dados[i].post_id + ',' + data.Dados[i].post_quantidade + ' )" class="form-control qtd_' + data.Dados[i].post_id + '" ' + data.Dados[i].disabled + ' min="1" max="' + data.Dados[i].post_quantidade + '" placeholder="0" required=""></td>';
   tr += '<td style="text-align:center;" class="subtotal-col">R$<span id="sub_' + data.Dados[i].post_id + '">0.00</span></td>';
   tr += '</tr>';
});
```

Estou precisando, limpar o sinal de -(menos), desse bendito campo input, porque se um cliente selecionar -1 os valores em tempo real irão ficar negativos, então não posso deixar de jeito nenhum esse -1 ser digitado, se for selecionar via setinhas do campo ele bloqueia, mais o problema é quando digita.

Eu penso que poderia ter uma expressão regular que fosse capaz de remover, mesmo digitando, ou então não permitir o sinal no campo.

Comment: propriedade min="0" resolve...

Comment: coisas assim encontra com facilidade em outros tópicos, google e afins....

Comment: essa propriedade min="0" quando vc digita o sinal menos aparece no input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algumas soluções:

```html
<input min='0' type="number" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
```

ou

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48" min="1" >
```

ou mesmo essa

```html
<input type="number" min="0" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)">
```

ou quem sabe essa

```html
<input type="number" name="test" min=0 oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
```

Comment: Resolvido com a 2ª opção

Answer (score 0):

utiliza a propriedade min="0"

```html
<input data-mask="00" data-mask-selectonfocus="true" style="margin:0;" onfocus="campoTexto(this, 1)" onblur="campoTexto(this, 0)" type="number" onChange="Multiplica(' + data.Dados[i].post_id + ',' + data.Dados[i].post_quantidade + ' )" class="form-control qtd_' + data.Dados[i].post_id + '" ' + data.Dados[i].disabled + ' min="1" max="' + data.Dados[i].post_quantidade + '" placeholder="0" required="" min="0">
```